# If two random variables share the same CDF, do they have identical distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> If two random variables share the same cdf, do they have identical distributions?

For example,   if $X_i$ is a collection of i.i.d random variables from the distribution of $X\sim B(8, 0.4)$, each having the same cdf as $X$, then $X_i\sim B(8, 0.4)$ for each $i = 1, ..., n$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, they do. The CDF is determining for the distribution.

Comment: So if X_i is a collection of i.i.d random variables from the distribution of X~B(8, 0.4), each having the same cdf as X, then X_i~B(8, 0.4) for each i = 1, ..., n. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.